# Plupload - Select Files Button doesnt work on various browsers

Tags: css, plupload

I have googled loads and tried various fixes including "uploader.refresh()" so am here asking your help please.

I am using the Core API for uploading and think maybe Ive tried to be too clever by replacing the `<a id="pickfiles"` with an image rather than text.

In doing so, the area for clicking is teeny on Firefox and IE which is causing problems for some of my users.

Ive tried to override the css:

```
a#pickfiles {
width: 150px;
height: 75px; 
}
```

but it doesnt make any difference, the height is still 15px.

Please can someone give me some pointers on how to sort this one.

Hope that all makes sense and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You’re aware that width and height don’t apply to inline elements? // Please go read [ask], and include code that makes the problem reproducible/a live example in your question.

Comment: No I wasnt aware of that but thank you for pointing it out.  So if that is the case, how do I get the image to be fully clickable please?   Re the code, what would you need to make the problem reproducable?  Cant give you a live example as the code is hidden behind login security

Comment: First we’d need to see what you did to make it _not_ fully clickable in the first place. [MCVE] explains how to create one; you can put it on a service like jsfiddle, codepen, or a similar service.